Why can't I use the letter B when switching already-opened files?
This is very weird and specific. I use Eclipse 2023-12 (4.30.0) on MacOS with Emacs key-bindings. Switching windows/tabs/files is initiated with Ctrl-X,b and then you can immediate type into a filter to narrow things down e.g. *.java or MyClass, etc.
For some reason, the letter b does nothing in this filter.
If I have an open buffer with the name Keyboard.java and I type Ctrl-X,b,Keyboard then the filter will show the word Keyoard (note the missing b) which will match nothing. No amount of backspacing, etc. will get the B key to type into that filter.
But the b key isn't being completely ignored. If I press b in that dialog, it seems to scroll-through the buffer names, with each keypress selecting a different buffer from the list.
If I choose Window > Navigation > Switch to Editor... (which is labeled with the shoertcut ^C ^B (note that's Ctrl-X,Ctrl-B instead of a bare B), I get a different dialog that does roughly the same thing. There is no "filter" box to type into, but typing does indeed search around within the list of open buffers. And the B key works, at least to the extent that any key works there... the rules are quite murky in there.
Is this a bug/oversight in Eclipse?

It sure sounds like a bug, did you search in the bug DB?

@MaartenBodewes Yes, I did search, but it's hard to search for "b" in the bug database :) Seriously, though, the search terms are all super generic.

I've filed a bug: https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/2023
